# how to download all files off a website (not the html file itself)

Tags: python, http

I need to download all files from the following website:

https://files.physics.byu.edu/data/prospr/

My initial thought was that I could just open it in filezilla and then download all the folders and the files in them, but I couldn't get that to work. Of course I could just download each file manually, but now I'm kinda interested in how this is done most smartly?

I have python installed and would be happy to use that for it if any convenient packages exist.

I did search around online for quite a while trying to find something to do this, but all I find are website scrapers that download entire webpages. So I would appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: HTTP doesn't provide a directory listing service, there's no way to download a whole site that way. You should use a file transfer protocol, which requires you to have a real login to the server.

Comment: You could use ```requests.get``` to get the source code of the URL with the files (e.g. https://files.physics.byu.edu/data/prospr/potts/), then get the URL of all of the downloadable files, not folders, on the web page by using the source code you got with ```requests.get```, then download the files with by doing [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/downloading-files-from-web-using-python). You would have to do this for every directory, but it will automatically download all of the files in that directory. Sorry if this sounds confusing, just let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using wget, which is a linux command, but it was possible to install under windows and then type in:

wget --recursive --reject "index.html" https://files.physics.byu.edu/data/prospr/